# Selecting Date of Birth using JCalendar in Java

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

I am developing a java desktop app. I wanna implement Date of Birth selecting using         JCalendar. I have a JLabel and this jCalendar is added to JLabel .And set position using setBounds().But the calendar is overlapping with other components and i can't select the date 
so what should i do?[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
    JCalendar dob=new JCalendar();

    raillabel. add(dob);

    dob.setBounds(250, 186, 320, 330);
```

Comment: there are two wrong things, 1. you shouldn't be use NullLayout, 2. have to set LayoutManager to JLabel (primary issue)

Comment: i need to use sebounds(); so the layout should be null ah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, why are you trying to add `JCalendar` to a `JLabel`? You can easily add this to a `JPanel`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JCalendar());
```

If you still want to add this `JCalendar` to a `JLabel` then you need to provide a [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to this last one in order to properly add components to it:

```
JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();        
JLabel label = new JLabel("Select date of birth:");
label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
label.add(calendar, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Take a look to [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

As @mKorbel says in his comment you shouldn't use `NullLayout` and `setBounds()` method to set the component location/size. This is the task layout managers are intended for.

Finally:

> I wanna implement Date of Birth selecting using `JCalendar`.

You may want to try `JDateChooser` instead, which allows selecting a date or type it by hand:

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
chooser.setLocale(Locale.US);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JLabel("Date of Birth:"));
panel.add(chooser);
```

#### Picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using swing, just place the jDateChooser control on your form and it will be just fine

Comment: i think u need to provide more details.